# Error while running R script in Python with SubProcess

Tags: python, r, subprocess

I am trying to run an R script that is in the same directory as the python script while executing the python script.

So far, I have:

```
if condition is True:
    import subprocess
    subprocess.call (["C:/Program Files/R/R-3.4.3/Rscript", "./testing.r"])
    sys.exit()
```

I keep getting the error:

```
OSError: [WinError 193] %1 is not a valid Win32 application
```

I've tried replacing  "C:/Program Files/R/R-3.4.3/Rscript"  with  "/usr/bin/Rscript"  but keep getting the same error. I was wondering if anybody would know why it keeps throwing this error?

Comment: Are sure this shouldn’t be submitted with cmd?

Comment: Try this `subprocess.call(['C:/Program Files/R/R-3.4.3/Rscript', '--vanilla', 'testing.r'], shell = True)` or provide the full path to the R script file

Comment: I guess the it might be a path problem. (The R version and Rscript path is for sure correct?) If yes, then give the full absolute path to `testing.r`, so 'C:/full/absolute/path/to/testing.r' (or is it in 'D:/' even)?

Comment: I've tried both suggestions but get an error that "C:/Program Files/R/R-3.4.3/Rscript" is not recognized as an external or internal command.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe the arguments of subprocess.call get passed straight to the command line, so you need to escape your quotation marks as such "\"C:/Program Files/R/R-3.4.3/Rscript\"". That being said, I get a [WinError 5] Access violation error when I use this. A workaround is to use the *executable* argument:

```
import sys
import subprocess

if True is True:
    subprocess.call(["C:/Program Files/R/R-3.4.3/Rscript.exe", "./testing.r"], 
                    executable="C:/Program Files/R/R-3.4.3/Rscript.exe")
    sys.exit()
```

Also, make sure that C:/Program Files/R/R-3.4.3/Rscript.exe is the location of your Rscript.exe. Mine is C:/Program Files/R/R-3.4.3/bin/Rscript.exe.

Comment: Yes, I was missing the "bin" in "C:/Program Files/R/R-3.4.3/bin/Rscript.exe". Thanks!